# What do you call a class that has no base class (ignoring object) and is not a subclass?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, types, terminology

I'm working on some code that needs to differentiate 3 scenarios of user-defined classes:

1. a class that other classes derive from; a base class
2. a class that derives from another user-defined class; an inherited class or subclass
3. a class that neither inherits (ignoring that all classes inherit from `object`, which is NOT user-defined) nor is a base class of any other class.

What's a good way to refer to #3?

Comment: Is it because inheritance is prohibited for the class, or because nobody has bothered to inherit from it yet?

Comment: Would #3 be `sealed` to prevent inheritance?

Comment: @GSerg - It's not strictly prohibited, but it will never make sense to inherit from it.

Comment: @Martin - Per my comment above, it should probably be sealed, although I'm not in the habit of sealing my types and using "sealed" to refer to it feels wrong, but that may in fact be the best term?

Comment: 1 - Superclass.  2- Child class. 3- There isn't really a standard name for this, because any class could be a parent class. In C# this would be a sealed class. In Java you would call it a final class. But these are language features, there isn't really a standard name for classes which cannot be inherited from. Outside of the keywords in certain languages there is nothing special about a class with no derivations.

Comment: @Martin is correct. This would be a `sealed` class (in C#). There isn't a formal name for this scenario, but I guess you could refer to it as 'non-subclassable'.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu `sealed` does not imply that the class itself may not inherit from other classes, which is also a requirement.

Comment: I've never heard about term for such class in C#, maybe it's worth to look into other languages? Or you can invent your own (if you write a book or documentation). Or simply call it `class`. Btw, you don't have to call base class always "base class". It only matter in context. Do you want to restrict *from* inheritance? Use `sealed`. Do you want to mention it has no parent? Probably say "not inherited" or "inherited from object".

Comment: Seems like there's consensus here that there's no great term for #3.  In code, I might describe how the class participates in a hierarchy.  Like maybe create an enum called HierarchyKind, with values HierarchyKind.None, HierarchyKind.BaseClass, HierarchyKind.InheritedClass.

Comment: I agree that there is no pithy term I'm aware of for making that distinction. I would caution you that you are falling into a very common trap amongst C#/Java/C++ programmers of conflating derivation and inheritance. That all these languages use derivation as the mechanism for inheritance does not imply that inheritance **is** derivation or derivation **is** inheritance; there are languages where derivation and inheritance are orthogonal. Remember, derivation is the "is a kind of" relationship, and inheritance is the "has the members of" relationship; they are not logically the same relation.

Comment: @EricLippert - Fair point!  I should have mentioned that the specific problem I'm working on is in a C#/.NET project, but I appreciate the reminder about not conflating derivation with inheritance.  Thank you!

Comment: The term `struct` comes in mind when reading the description of #3 :) Other than that I agree with @Sinatr *simply call it class*

Comment: I think conceptually it'd be like an "orphan", a parent-less class...  It's essentially what a POCO is.

Comment: "It's not strictly prohibited, but it will never make sense to inherit from it." - Well, if it never make sense to inherit from it, you might as well strictly prohibit that by adding the sealed keyword to the class declaration. Anyway, I agree with whomever wrote it first - just call it a class.

Comment: @EricLippert That's the first time I've encountered this particular explanation of inheritance ("has a member of") - care to elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I'm not sure what to expand upon; that's pretty much it. The C# specification defines "inheritance" as *When a type inherits from a base class, all members of the base class, except instance constructors, destructors and static constructors, become members of the derived type.* In other words, inheritance is the "has the members of" relationship. It did not have to be that way; the designers of C# chose to make inheritance tied tightly to derivation.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: A general discussion of languages that make a stronger distinction between subtyping, subclassing, conversion and inheritance would take rather more than a comment. A good language to study in this regard is OCAML, which allows subtyping without subclassing and subclassing without subtyping. The various kinds of polymorphism in OCAML are very interesting.

Comment: @EricLippert yes, but going back to the basics for a second - `class Animal {}`, `class Mammal : Animal {}` and `class Dog : Mammal {}` - The Dog class inherits the Mammal class which in turn inherits the Animal class - you can say that a dog is a kind of mammal and a mammal is a kind of animal, and you can also say that because of that, a dog has the members of a mammal which has the members of an animal - I don't see the separation here - but then again, perhaps it's just because I've only worked with .Net (and a long long time ago, Java)...

Comment: @EricLippert I'll take a look at OCAML when I get a chance, thanks!

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Indeed, you think of those as "the basics" because that's the world you've been immersed in; the decisions of those language designers long ago seem like bedrock principles when in fact they are choices. Now imagine a type system where we say "call the type that is the union of all dogs, cats and fish the pet type". With this definition, the type that is all dogs is a *subtype* of the pet type, but surely we would not say that it *derives* from that type, nor that it *inherits* the methods of the pet type.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks! That makes a lot of sense now. I knew you could explain it :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a **non-integrated class**.

Vertical integration is the extension of a process, meaning new additional steps. This is a business decision regarding operations, and you can learn a lot from McKinsey's online article here:  https://www.mckinsey.com/business-functions/strategy-and-corporate-finance/our-insights/when-and-when-not-to-vertically-integrate

When you hear business people use the term integration, it can refer to horizontal (new products and product lines) or vertical.

Wikipedia uses the term "non-integrated" when describing control system instrumentation. I constantly correct programmers that this means "the thing is not a step in some process. It is a separate device, not a function call." And it doesn't help when programmers try to pass themselves off as experts in control systems while completely misusing this term. I am happy to give you the authoritative business world jargon.

What McKinsey says about site specificity and integration is covered in my web article on the subject. Be aware we don't agree on everything. http://www.powersemantics.com/o.html